# Read txt file into array and assign to variables

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

So essentially what I need to do is make this while loop run through the txt file and store it in an array to be stored inside the instance variables

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * <insert class description here>
 *
 * @author Chris Crosby
 *
 */
public class TrackInput
{
    private Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int readTrackData(Railroad[] Reservations) {
        final String FILE_NAME = "TrackData.txt";
        int size =0;
        Scanner input = null;
        try { 
            input= new Scanner(new File(FILE_NAME));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file " + FILE_NAME + ".");
        }
        String passengerName="";
        String routeNumber="";
        String departureDate="";
        String departureTrack="";
        String arrivalTrack="";
        String departureTime="";
        String arrivalTime="";
        String seat="";
        String returnRouteNumber="";
        String ReturnDate="";


        while (input.hasNext()&& size<Reservations.length) {

        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

here's the txt file that the loop is reading through

```
Carl Foreman
1234
UA1235
06/23/2014
ORD
LGA
4:00 PM
7:15 PM
23A
UA673
07/12/2014
LGA
ORD
10:00 AM
11:25 AM
8A
Jennifer Foreman
1235
UA1235
06/23/2014
ORD
LGA
4:00 PM
7:15 PM
23B
UA673
07/12/2014
LGA
ORD
10:00 AM
11:25 AM
8B
Jane Anderson
4577
UA317
08/04/2014
ORD
SFO
8:10 AM
10:45 AM
11C
UA728
08/14/2014
SFO
ORD
12:52 PM
7:03 PM
10D
Jason Anderson
4578
```

**TrackData.txt format**

- passenger name – include first and last name in one variable
- reservation number
- departure route number
- departure date
- departure track
- arrival track
- departure time
- arrival time
- seat
- return route number
- return date
- departure track
- arrival track
- departure time
- arrival time
- seat

here's a similar method I had to write for a previous assignment

```
public int readInventory(Automobile[] inventory)
    {
        final String FILENAME = "inventory.csv";
        int size = 0;

        Scanner input = null;
        try
        {
            input = new Scanner(new File(FILENAME));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file " + FILENAME + ".");
        }

        // read header line and discard first line
        String line = input.nextLine();

        // create vars
        int year = 0;
        String make = "";
        String model = "";
        double price = 0.0;
        String condition = "";
        int rating = 0;
        String status = "";
        String vin = "";

        // Customer vars
        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        String streetAddress = "";
        String city = "";
        String state = "";
        String zip = "";
        String email = "";
        String phone = "";

        while (input.hasNext() && size < inventory.length)
        {
            line = input.nextLine();
            String[] record = line.split(",");

            year = Integer.parseInt(record[0]);
            make = record[1];
            model = record[2];

            // If use this version, comment out the following if statements

            if (!(record[3].equals("")))
            {
                price = Double.parseDouble(record[3]);
            }
            else
            {
                price = 0;
            }

            condition = record[4];

            if (!(record[5].equals("")))
            {
                rating = Integer.parseInt(record[5]);
            }
            else
            {
                rating = 0;
            }

            status = record[6];
            vin = record[7];

            // this is where the records differ
            // they either don't have buyer information or some do

            if (record.length > 8) 
            {
                if (!(record[8].equals("")))
                    firstName = record[8];
                else
                    firstName = "";

                if (!(record[9].equals("")))
                    lastName = record[9];
                else
                    lastName = "";

                if (!(record[10].equals("")))
                    streetAddress = record[10];
                else
                    streetAddress = "";

                if (!(record[11].equals("")))
                    city = record[11];
                else
                    city = "";

                if (!(record[12].equals("")))
                    state = record[12];
                else
                    state = "";

                if (!(record[13].equals("")))   
                    zip = record[13];
                else
                    zip = "";

                if (!(record[14].equals("")))
                    email = record[14];
                else
                    email = "";

                if (!(record[15].equals("")))
                    phone = record[15];
                else
                    phone = "";

            }

            // changes to integrate Customer class go below

            Customer tempCustomer = new Customer(firstName,lastName, city, state, email, phone,zip,streetAddress);          
            Automobile tempAutomobile = new Automobile( year, make, model, price, 
                    condition, rating, status, vin, tempCustomer);

            inventory[size] = tempAutomobile;
            size++;

        } // end of while loop

        input.close();

        return size;
    }
```

not sure how to make it work for this program since this is multilined and the previous was a single line separated by commas hence the line.split

Comment: What is your question? What is your problem? What have you tried? Stackoverflow is not designed as a "do this for me" site, you come here to ask question about topics you have already researched.

Comment: my question is just any sort of hint or direction for what to do here as I've tried a for loop and similar methods to no avail

Comment: change input.hasNext() to input.hasNextLine() since you are grabbing line by line with the call input.nextLine()

Comment: Why not use a BufferedReader instead of a Scanner?

Comment: @Geoff because this is the method that my professor taught in lecture

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I am not sure i should answer this since it is not that hard and i am sure you can solve it yourself. Sadly i dont have enough reputation to just comment (that is why i am here in the first place).

I will just drop some hints to help you:

1) You know how to read line by line. You can choose when to start, stop and even skip lines. Sadly you can only move forward but that is enough for this problem.

2) The data file follows a constant pattern. This means this is the easy to handle data.

3) You know the pattern beforehand. Pst, it is the OP!

I think that is it. Now you should just pay attention and wait for the AHA! moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
package edu.ilstu;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * <insert class description here>
 *
 * @author Chris Crosby
 *
 */
public class TrackInput
{
    public final String TRANSACTION_FILE = "Transactions.txt";
    public final String DATA_FILE = "RailroadData.txt";

    public TrackInput() {

    }
    Scanner transaction = null;
    public Scanner readTransactions() {
        try {
            transaction= new Scanner(new File(TRANSACTION_FILE));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Unable to open file" + TRANSACTION_FILE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return transaction;
    }
    public char readTransactionCode() {
        char choice = transaction.nextLine().charAt(0);
        return choice;
    }
    public int readRailroadData(Reservation [] reservations) {
        Scanner data;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            data = new Scanner(new File(DATA_FILE));
            while(data.hasNext()) {
                Reservation reservation = readReservationData(data);
                reservations [count] = reservation;
                count++;
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Unable to open file" + DATA_FILE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return count;
    }
    public Reservation readReservationData(Scanner input) {
        String name = input.nextLine();
        String departureReservationNumber=input.nextLine();
        String departureRouteNumber = input.nextLine();
        String departureRouteDate = input.nextLine();
        String departureTrack = input.nextLine();
        String departureArrivalTrack = input.nextLine();
        String departureTime = input.nextLine();
        String departureArrivalTime = input.nextLine();
        String departureSeatAssignment = input.nextLine();

        String returnRoute = input.nextLine();
        String returnDate = input.nextLine();
        String returnDepartureTrack = input.nextLine();
        String returnArrivalTrack = input.nextLine();
        String returnDepartureTime = input.nextLine();
        String returnArrivalTime = input.nextLine();
        String returnSeatAssignment = input.nextLine();
        Route departureRoute = new Route(departureRouteNumber, departureRouteDate, departureTrack, departureArrivalTrack,departureTime, departureArrivalTime, departureSeatAssignment);
        Route arrivalRoute= new Route(returnRoute, returnDate, returnDepartureTrack, returnArrivalTrack,returnDepartureTime,returnArrivalTime,returnSeatAssignment);
        Reservation reservation = new Reservation(name,departureReservationNumber, departureRoute, arrivalRoute);
        return reservation;
    }
    public int addReservationToList(Reservation[] reservationList,Reservation reservation, int size) {
        reservationList[size] = reservation;
        size++;
        return size;
    }

}
```